# expandableListView android header background

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Was just wondering how to change the background of headers in a expandableListView when they are extended (the headers).

I'd like not to do it programmatically but more with a selector or whatever XML property.

So question : Is there any way to know when a header is extended or not ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was just about setting a drawable to my headers like this

```
android:background="@drawable/expandable_list_headers"
```

And then create a custom drawable to change the background like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:drawable="@color/LightBlue" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<!-- pressed -->
<item android:drawable="@color/LightBlue" android:state_focused="true"/>
<!-- focused -->
<item android:drawable="@color/LightBlue" android:state_selected="true"/>
<!-- selected -->
<item android:drawable="@color/LightBlue" android:state_expanded="true"/>

<item android:drawable="@color/White" android:state_expanded="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/White"/>
<!-- default -->
```

Comment: When I do this, the background of the entire ExpandableListView is changed, not each header.  Could you offer a hint on how to fix this?